# if this.somefield refers to the object say X that is initialized by "using" statement, will garbage collector makes X to be null in the future?

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, using

there is a c# class having some fields (p1,p2,p3)and in one of the method, 
p1 gets initialized as

```
using(Object X = new Object()){
this.p1 = X ;
}
```

After the closure of using block, anytime later Will X be collected by garbage collector and this.p1 becomes null because of that

OR

Because of the reference to X from this.p1 , will X never become null till application is killed?

Comment: First of all, you don't have a reference to `X`. What you do have are two references to the same object in memory, one is stored in `X` and the other in `this.p1`. As long as one or both of these references still "lives", the object is considered ineligible for garbage collection.

Comment: Also note that the presence of `using` (if we ignore the fact that `Object` does not implement `IDisposable`, I take this as "a type that implements IDisposable"), will not have an impact on garbage collection of this object. Calling `Dispose` on this object, which happens at the end of that using statement, may make that object clear out some of its internal references to both managed and unmanaged memory, but the object itself is still following the same rule as I said in my other comment, as long as the reference in `this.p1` still "lives", the object is not eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: And no, X will not become null. If X is still in use, whatever X refers to is ineligible for garbage collection. Once X is no longer in use, that reference is no longer used to keep the object alive (though `this.p1` might), but then you can no longer observe the value of X either.

Comment: Typically you would use `X` to do something, so `this.p1 = X.DoSomething()` and then disposing `X` is ok. But you can also implement `IDisposable` and abuse it for exact that scenario (allowing `Dispose()` call for some other purpose). As for questions: neither is true, `p1` will not change its value unless you set it, and since `p1` will hold reference it may cause memory leaks, this has nothing to do with `using`, it's about lifetime of `this`.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you work in the same scope of `X` creation, `X` will never be elegible for collection.

As long as the `object` referred by `this` will be alive, `X` will never be elegible for collection, cause `this.p1` is referring to `X`.

Comment: [Corrected the question] After the closure of using block, will GC collect X ? My understanding is because of the reference to X from this.P1 , X won't be collected by GC

Comment: Exactly as I stated on my answer